# How to apply padding to a column using <col> and CSS in Firefox?

Tags: css, html-table, padding

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #col-1 {
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: tan;
    }
    #specific-cell {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
</style>
<table>
    <col id="col-1">
    <col id="col-2">
    <tr>
        <th>foo</th>
        <th>bar</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</th>
        <td>data2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="specific-cell">data1</th>
        <td>data2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data1</th>
        <td>data2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The color is applied to the column but not the padding. If I use classes/ids on cells directly, it works.

Am I forced to use them, or is there a way taking advantage of the `<col>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not supposed to work, at least with CSS 2.1. You may have a look at the [CSS 2.1 table columns specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns).

You can circumvent this by using `:first-child` and `+`:

```
/* first column */
td:first-child {
    padding-left: 20px;  
}

/* second column */ 
td:first-child + td {
    padding-left: 10px;  
}

/* third columns */ {
td:first-child + td + td {
    padding-left: 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in IE with the following DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

and the styles

```
#col-1 {
    padding-left: 50px;
    background-color: tan;
}
#col-2 {
    padding-left: 100px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

What doctype are you using... and what browser are you using...

hmm... just checked doesn't seem to work in Firefox

Comment: How useless without browser information, I'm sorry. Yes, it's FF, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer works for me, except it's not very scalable for lots of columns and quickly becomes hard to read. I ended up using `:nth-of-type(n)` instead, however this selector was introduced in CSS3.

Selector:  `:nth-of-type(n)`
Example:   `p:nth-of-type(2)`
Result:    Selects every `<p>` element that is the second `<p>` element of its parent

Example:

```
/*column 1*/
#myTable td:nth-of-type(1)
{
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: tan;
}
/*column 2*/
#myTable td:nth-of-type(2)
{
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```